# Submitting HTML from CKEditor in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor with JQuery AJAX and ASP.NET MVC.

I am trying to perform an AJAX POST with JQuery but it fails to submit because of the HTML in the textarea. The form submits fine if I just enter plain text in a textarea, but not as HTML.

The JQuery method I am using to get the HTML from the textarea is .val()

Can someone tell me how to fix this problem please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use [GetData](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#getData)  and also make sure your controller action that accepts the post has this annotation applied [HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]

Answer (score 1):

I did not succeed in that so if you are not required to use CKEditor you can switch to tinymce which you can add via NuGet  (install-package TinyMCE.MVC) and this works fine with MVC